# ASP page in IIS 7.5

Tags: sql-server, authentication, asp-classic, iis-7.5

I have deployed ASP page on IIS 7.5. ASP page communicates with the SQL server using windows auhtentication. I get the error, "login failed for user 'Intranet/ServerName'". I did all the settings according to the thread [Classic ASP problem connecting to remote SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1139772/classic-asp-problem-connecting-to-remote-sql-server-database)   , but still no work. Which setting I need to amend to make IIS to connsider credentials of user account for windows authentication rather than machine name?

Comment: 1. what version of SQL Server you are using?
2. are you in domain? 
3. does SQL Server running with IIS on the same computer?
4. how quick you get error "login failed"? in few seconds or after 30..60 seconds?

Comment: Can you post the code you are using to connect to your database please?